# Orchard Background tasks

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I ve been wondering does orchard create a new thread each time it sweeps after 60 secondes ?

lets say for instance you have a background task which can be multiple tasks that we'll iterate :

```
public class MyBackGroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Sweep()
    {
        var AwaitingTasks = _TasksServices.GetAwaitingTasks();
        foreach(var awaitingTask in AwaitingTasks)
        {
            // do something 
        }
    }
}
```

those tasks can take up to 30 minutes for example . does orchard creates a new thread for the Sweep() after one minute or he'll wait for the previous executed task to end ?

if so is there any good approach i can take to create a good queuing system ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps check `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and see if you get a different id than the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

Orchard has a processing engine that allows you to delay processing of a long running task to a background thread, which may be more what you are after?

Have look in the comments module, the CommentsService has a method called process comment count which should serve as a good example of how the processing engine works.

Comment: the issue here is .  the backgroundTask is never fired once again until the previous executed one is finished.

Comment: If this is the case you can use the background task to fire off the processing engine to handle your 30 minute task, no?

Comment: I didn't quiet understand your reply . but what i want is the backgroudtask Sweep Method which is supposed to be fired every one minute , will be fired after every one minute even if the recent fired one  is not finished yet .

Comment: Every sweep() call should be called in a separate thread so it shouldn't care about the (Sweeps()) fired earlier it should fire new one every time one minute hits without having to wait the sweeps which runs on separate threads

Comment: Yes, so you can offload the heavy processing from your background task to the processing engine to be run in a different thread, which will free up the sweep thread. Though I do admit that it is a little strange the sweep method has to wait for the previous sweep to finish...